# wordpress is_category of all subcategories of parent category

Tags: wordpress, post

i want to show a certien code inside all posts (single.php) that are assosiated with all sub cats of one father cat. i want the code to work for all this post who are under this sub cats (that are under the main cat)

i have tryed this:

```
<?php function get_child_cats( $catname ) {
    $parentcat = get_cat_ID(8);
    $subcat = get_categories( array('child_of' => $parentcat ) );
    $cat_array = array();
    array_push($cat_array, $parentcat); // add the parent cat to the array
    foreach ($subcat as $sc) {
        array_push($cat_array, $sc->cat_ID);
    }
    return $cat_array;
}?>
```

and this:

```
<?php  if (in_category(8) && !is_feed()) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it is done:

```
<?php $mycats = array(8);
    foreach (get_the_category() as $childcat) {
        foreach ($mycats as $mycat) {
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of($mycat, $childcat)) { ?>
<ul> <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=1&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=8'); ?></ul>
             <?php   break 2;
            }
        }
    } ?>
```